# Javascript add item to current array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I am trying to add an item to a current array.

```
var arrayValues = new Array();
arrayValues.push("Value 1");
arrayValues.push("Value 2");
arrayValues = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
arrayValues.push("Value 3");
```

By doing this way I get a error, and I dont get value 1 and value 2, after getting the hyperlink collection when I try to add a new item it throws Error: Object doesn't support this property or method which is the push method.

What is happening to the array after the collection of hyperlinks is assigned ? How can I add a new item to it ?

Answer (score 14):

Did you mean `arrayValues.push(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));`?

Otherwise, you're assigning the `NodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName()`, which overwrites the array you had just pushed values into.

Side note: there's no reason to use `new Array()` here. Just write `var arrayValues = [];`.

Comment: And NodeList isn't an Array, though it is "array-like."

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push all `<a>` elements to the array, you have to convert the NodeList to an array first. Most people use `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist)`.

Once you have an array, you can then use `array.push` in conjunction with [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) to push them in one call.

The resulting code looks like:

```
var arrayValues = [];
arrayValues.push("Value 1");
arrayValues.push("Value 2");
arrayValues.push.apply(arrayValues, Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a')));
arrayValues.push("Value 3");
```

Comment: You don't need to `apply` the call to `push`. `arrayValues` is already an array, and a call to `arrayValues.push()` will execute the right function (`push`) in the right scope (`arrayValues`).

Comment: I actually want to send multiple arguments to `.push()`. For example, `var a=[], b=[2,3];`, if you `a.push(1);a.push(b);a.push(4)`, then `a` is `[1,[2,3],4]`. However, if you use `a.push.apply(a,b);`, you will get `[1,2,3,4]`. That's the expected behavior of this answer: push all `<a>` elements to an existing array. You can also say that it's a version of `a = a.concat(b);`.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. In which case, why not just use `concat()`?